# Single post not synching after updating in angular-fullstack app

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, socket.io, yeoman

In my Angular-fullstack app, posting posts on my post overview page works. The problem is: when i post a comment on a single post page (push it to the post and update), my socket update does not work.

My schema:

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  title: String,
  body: String,
  comments: [{ name: String, body: String, date: { type: Date, default: Date.now } }],
  active: Boolean
});
```

posts.controller (works like a charm)

```
.controller('PostsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, socket) {
  $http.get('/api/posts').success(function(posts) {
    $scope.posts = posts;
    socket.syncUpdates('post', $scope.posts, function(event, post, posts) {
    });
  });

  $scope.addPost = function(){
      $http.post('/api/posts', { title: $scope.title, body: $scope.body, link: $scope.link });
      $scope.title = '';
      $scope.body = '';
      $scope.link = '';
  };
});
```

post.controller,does not update when i post a comment:

```
.controller('PostCtrl', function ($scope, $http, socket, $stateParams) {

  $http.get('/api/posts/' + $stateParams.id).success(function(post) {
    $scope.post = post;

    socket.syncUpdates('post', $scope.post);
  });

  $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    socket.unsyncUpdates('post');
  });

  $scope.addComment = function(){
      $http.post('/api/posts/' + $stateParams.id + '/comments', { name: "NAAM", body: "BODY" });
  };

});
```

The comment gets saved to the database, but a refresh is required to update the ng-repeat. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You 're not updating your view. Try this

```
.controller('PostCtrl', function($scope, $http, socket, $stateParams) {

    // Update the view (put this in a function, so you could call it again when needed)
    function updateView(){
        $http.get('/api/posts/' + $stateParams.id).success(function(post) {
            $scope.post = post;

            socket.syncUpdates('post', $scope.post);
        });            
    }
    // Then call it, first time 
    updateView();

    $scope.addComment = function() {
        $http.post('/api/posts/' + $stateParams.id + '/comments', {
            name: "NAAM",
            body: "BODY"
        });

        // And then each time you post a comment
        updateView();
    };

});
```

---

Or, update the view directly. I'm not sure what your `$scope.post` is supposed to contain but if it's an array, and the new data is `{ name: "NAAM", body: "BODY" }` you can push it

```
.controller('PostCtrl', function($scope, $http, socket, $stateParams) {

    $scope.addComment = function() {
        $http.post('/api/posts/' + $stateParams.id + '/comments', {
            name: "NAAM",
            body: "BODY"
        });

        // update your view
        $scope.post.push({ name: "NAAM", body: "BODY" });
    };

});
```

You can also choose to update the view directly without fetching from server. I'm not exactly sure what your `$scope.post` is and how your `socket.syncUpdates` actually updates your views but if you can manage to do that directly, then indeed you'll be using the 'two-way binding' by directly updating the `$scope`

Comment: This seems to work. But it seems to me like this isn't two-way binding right? In my posts controller the posts get fetched on the fly, while i am not wrapping the $http request in a function.

Comment: The term 'two-way binding' in Angular is for DOM <==> $scope, it doesn't not include the server. Your `$scope.post` is dependent on fetching ($http.get) data from the server.